# How to compute a thumbnail filename from the shell?

Tags: shell, hashsum, printf

I started noticing some time ago in Xfce4 that when I sent some file to the Trash, tumbler (the Xfce4 thumbnailer) would cause very high I/O load for quite some time. Upon investigating the issue, I found that it was scanning the ~/.thumbnails directory, which was very large in size.

So I decided to write a cron script that will periodically clean the ~/.thumbnails directory, but there is a certain directory of large video files that tumbler takes a bit of time, and sometimes even fails, to create thumbnails for.

The idea is removing all thumbnails, except the ones for these videos. But in order to keep these thumbnails, I have to find what their names are. The problem is that thumbnails are stored named with a md5sum of the URI, plus the PNG extension.

Upon looking at [the tumbler source](http://sources.debian.net/src/tumbler/0.1.25-1/plugins/xdg-cache/xdg-cache-cache.c?hl=551#L527), I found the name for the thumbnail is generated in the following line:

```
md5_hash = g_compute_checksum_for_string (G_CHECKSUM_MD5, uri, -1);
```

The [documentation for g-compute-checksum-for-string](https://developer.gnome.org/glib/2.28/glib-Data-Checksums.html#g-compute-checksum-for-string) says:

```
g_compute_checksum_for_string(GChecksumType checksum_type,
                              const gchar *str,
                              gssize length);

checksum_type: a GChecksumType 
str:           the string to compute the checksum of
length:        the length of the string, or -1 if the string is null-terminated.
```

To put it short, the thumbnail for a file named `/home/teresaejunior/File 01.png` will be stored in the .thumbnails/ directory as `a8502be3273541e618b840204479a7f9.png`

According to the [ThumbnailerSpec](https://wiki.gnome.org/ThumbnailerSpec#Request_the_creation_of_thumbnails), URI is `file://filename`. I did some research on the "null character", and thought `\0` would do the trick. In order to achieve the result `a8502be3273541e618b840204479a7f9`, I believed the following should work:

```
printf "file:///home/teresaejunior/File 01.png\0" | md5sum
```

but that returns `f507285c45d293fa66bc0b813d17b6e6` instead.

Can someone give me some advice? I believe my `printf` line is flawed. What is my command doing different from `g_compute_checksum_for_string`?

Comment: No, that string returns that hash here. `>>> m = hashlib.md5('file:///home/teresaejunior/File 01.png\0')`
`>>> m.hexdigest()`
`'f507285c45d293fa66bc0b813d17b6e6'`

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams The thumbnail for this file is stored as `a8502be3273541e618b840204479a7f9`, although it was generated by the function I mentioned. Please, click on the link for the tumbler source for details.

Comment: Right, but the NUL in your command is not the problem.

Comment: Can't answer, but you can confirm that you are indeed printing the null string by passing through `od`: `printf "file:///home/teresaejunior/File 01.png\0" | od -c`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The NUL character is not included when the MD5 is calculated.  Rather, it's the space character that's causing your problem.  The filename is [URL-encoded](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding):

```
$ printf '%s' 'file:///home/teresaejunior/File%2001.png' | md5sum
a8502be3273541e618b840204479a7f9  -
```

Here's one way to do the conversion with Perl:

```
$ perl -MURI::file -MDigest::MD5=md5_hex \
  -e 'printf "%s.png\n", md5_hex(URI::file->new(shift))' \
  '/home/teresaejunior/File 01.png'
a8502be3273541e618b840204479a7f9.png
```