# How could one, given a thumbnail image in ~/.cache/thumbnails, find the originally thumbnailed image?

Tags: imagemagick, thunar, thumbnails

I understand that Thunar utilizes [`tumbler`](https://docs.xfce.org/xfce/thunar/tumbler) to generate thumbs, and I know these thumbs exist on my system in `~/.cache/thumbnails`.

My goal is to write a script to check for the existence of a thumbnail on-disk for a given image or PDF. This script would be used in a workflow for quickly manipulating bulk-scanned paper documents and other images in a custom web UI.

Is there a clever way to reverse-lookup the thumbnail and make a copy, so I don't need to invoke a library to re-generate for my purposes?

Filenames are obscure number-strings.

I'm using Thunar on Debian 10.

Answer (score 1):

Based on a bit more research I found [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/91325/how-to-compute-a-thumbnail-filename-from-the-shell)

So I am able to do something like:

`> printf '%s' 'file:///home/kf/inbox/random-document.pdf' | md5sum`

This successfully generates the correct filename.